# Retrieve an annotated field from a class in the view

Tags: java, annotations, jstl, taglib, custom-tags

In my current spring project, the atributes from my entity classes have annotations to indicate which type of form control should be used for data input, like this:

```
@Column(name = "login", unique=true)
@Order(value=1)
@Input(name="login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "senha")
@Order(value=2)
@Input(type="password", name="senha")
private String senha;

@Column(name="nome")
@Order(value=3)
@Input(name="nome")
private String nome;

@Column(name="sobrenome")
@Order(value=4)
@Input(name="sobrenome")
private String sobrenome;

@Column(name="email")
@Order(value=5)
@Input(name="email")
private String email;
```

And I have custom tags which should read the atributes of the annotations and add to the page the correct tag, like that:

```
public class InputTag extends TagSupport {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doTag() throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        String name = this.getName();
        String type = this.getType();
        String pattern = this.getPattern();

        if(type == null) {
            if(pattern == "") {
                out.println("<form:input path=\""+name+"\" class=\"form-control\"/>");
            } else {
                out.println("<form:input path=\""+name+"\" class=\"form-control valida\" pattern=\""+pattern+"\"/>");
            }
        } else {
            if(pattern == "") {
                out.println("<form:input path=\""+name+"\" type=\""+type+"\" class=\"form-control\"/>");
            } else {
                out.println("<form:input path=\""+name+"\" type=\""+type+"\" class=\"form-control valida\" pattern=\""+pattern+"\"/>");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

the getter methods from the tag class have this format:

```
private String getName() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    Field field = null;
    Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(Input.class);
    Input inputAnnotation = (Input) annotation;
    String name = inputAnnotation.name();
    return name;
}
```

What I need right now it's a way of store in the variable `field` the field I want add to he page. I know the method for do this if I was inside the entity class (something like `getClass().getField("<nome>")`), but how I access this information from my tag class?

The view is mapped in my controller this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
public String cadastra(Model model) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    model.addAttribute("command", this.entity.newInstance());
    return "private/cadastrar";
}
```

and the jsp code in this moment it's this (just the basic structure):

```
<c:url value="/${entity}/cadastra" var="cadastra"/>
<form:form method="POST" action="${cadastra}" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button>

</form:form>
```

Anyone knows a way to accomplish this?